# Finder file size easy way

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, filesystem, file

While showing items as icons (not in a list, in columns or wit cover flow).

In order to know file size I right-click the file then select `Get info` then a window opens full of info and I have to look around just to find file size.

Is there some way to make it easier? May be hold `Command` while hover over file..

Comment: Deleted my answer as this is now a totally different question - it would have been helpful to have been clear in the first place...

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault @SolarMike (totally agree with you), but now question correctly express what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 5):

There's no *perfect* built-in macOS solution for what you want, and that's why macOS offers different view options. They each have advantages and disadvantages.

However, the closest option to what you want would be to enable the **Show item info** option.

To do this:

1. Within Finder navigate to the folder you're wanting to view
2. Make sure it's in Icon view
3. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (or just right lick on the window and select *Show View Options*)
4. Now you'll see the view options for icon view
5. Tick the *Show item info* checkbox

[image]

6. OPTIONAL: If you want this to apply to all windows with icon view, click on the <kbd>Use as Defaults</kbd> button at the bottom
7. Close the *Show View Options* window

Now you'll notice additional info is displayed below your icons

**NOTES:**

- The reason this is not a *perfect* solution in your case is that the info displayed below the icon is not necessarily the file size. That is, while for many files it does display the file size, for others it will display different info (e.g. if it's a folder it'll display the number of items inside the folder, if it's an image it'll display the image dimensions, etc).
- Not all file types will have additional info displayed.
- I have found that sometimes you need to disable and then re-enable this option after copying items from another location across, otherwise the info isn't displayed immediately below the icon.

Despite the above limitations, enabling this will reduce the number of times you need to use Get Info to view the file size.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate solution that may work for you.

Save this following code in ScriptEditor.app, as an application.  Then in Finder.app, while holding down the command key, drag that script editor application you just saved, to the Finder's toolbar.  Now anytime you have a file selected in Finder, click that .app you just moved to the toolbar, and it will display a dialog with the file size of the currently selected file.

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set fileSize to size of item 1 of (get selection)
    on error errMsg number errNum
        activate
        display alert ¬
            "Selected File Info" message ¬
            "There Is No Selected File In Finder" buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button ¬
            "OK" giving up after 4
        return
    end try
end tell

copy fileSize as string to fileSize2

set tempList to text items of fileSize2 as string
set tempList to tempList as inches as text -- Workaround For Displaying Large Numbers Correctly
try
    set kiloBytes to ((items -4 thru 1) of tempList & "." & (items -1 thru -3) of tempList)
    set theMessage to "The File Size Is " & kiloBytes & " Kilobytes"
on error errMsg number errNum
    set theMessage to "The File Size Is " & fileSize & " Bytes"
end try

activate
display alert ¬
    "Selected File Info" message theMessage ¬
    buttons {"OK"} ¬
    default button ¬
    "OK" giving up after 4
```

[image]

Comment: I love the animated answer here. Well done, indeed. I feel bad no one else gave a +1 yet - hopefully over time this and other answers will get some vote love.

Comment: I think maybe I would have gotten more votes on my solution, had I posted  it the same day as the original post